# G delta sets and denseness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and is complete. As $G_\delta$ sets are the countable intersection of open sets. So if $G_\delta$ is a dense set in $X$ then does this implies that the open sets whose intersection was $G_\delta$ is also dense.

Comment: If $G_\delta=\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty U_n$ is dense, where each $U_n$ is an open set, then $G_\delta\subseteq U_n$ for every $n$, so each $U_n$ must de dense.

Comment: Any superset of a dense set is dense.

Comment: $D$ is dense in $X$ iff every non-empty open set in $X$ meets $D$. Clearly in that case every non-empty open set in $X$ also meets every superset of $D$, so every superset of $D$ is also dense.

Comment: @Darsen is denseness transitive property then ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *transitivity*. If you're referring to the fact that sets containing a dense set are dense themselves; it's true. See my answer below.

Comment: I meant if $A\subset B \subset C $ and $A$ is dense in $B$, $B$ is dense in $C$ then is $A$ is dense in $C$.

Comment: Yes. If you have a nonempty open set $U$, then $C\cap U$ is an open set in the relative topology of $C$, so $B\cap (C\cap U)=B\cap U$ isn't empty, and it is an open set in the relative topology of $B$. Therefore $A\cap(B\cap U)=A\cap U$ isn't empty either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some users and I pointed out in the comments, any set that contains a dense set has to be dense. Let's see why:

Imagine $D$ is dense and $D\subseteq A$. Take any open set $U$. Since $D$ is dense, $D\cap U\neq\emptyset$, so there is some $x\in D\cap U$. Then $x\in D$ and $x\in U$. Since $D\subseteq A$, $x\in A$ too, so $x\in A\cap U$. All this is just saying that given $D\subseteq A$ we have $\emptyset\neq D\cap U\subseteq A\cap U$. Since $U$ was a non-specific open set, this works for every open set, so we conclude that $A$ is dense too.

As for your question, as I said, if a dense set $D$ is a $G_\delta$, then it is a countable intersection of open sets: $D=\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty U_n$. Since $D=\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty U_n\subseteq U_n$ for every $n$, we have that each $U_n$ is dense.

Comment: *Since* $U$ *was a generic open set* --- Was this an intentional play on words? (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2427664/13130) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22generic%22+%22baire+category%22).)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unaware of the use of such word for that definition! I corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I thought it was unintentional, but sometimes people take pride in subtle word play fun, seeing if anyone notices.